Integrating libpulse's pa_threaded_mainloop in a Qt application (hacking pavucontrol-qt)
I'm trying to get pavucontrol-qt (pvcq) to work properly on Mac (yes, PulseAudio works there).
The hurdle here is that the Qt/Mac event dispatcher is not based on GLib, so qvcq's current implementation using a pa_glib_mainloop (that somehow hooks into Qt's GLib-based mainloop) doesn't work.
I have thus implemented alternative code paths where a pa_threaded_mainloop is used instead, taking care that all libpulse callbacks that interact with the GUI do this on the main loop, via QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qApp, [=]() {qApp->pa_callback(...);}, Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection).
That works but the application also uses a delayed event handler installed via g_idle_add() and I cannot seem to manage to write an alternative, GLib-based implementation.
I had hoped that it would be a simple question of making certain the call to g_idle_add() was placed from the pa_threaded_mainloop but I until now that question has proven to be not simple at all.
The function calling the required g_idle_add() is executed on the main thread because part of the GUI functions. So what I tried is to create an instance (paThread) of a custom class inheriting QObject and send it to QThread::currentThread() at an appropriate moment during the initial startup when pa_threaded_mainloop_in_thread() returns true. That bit works, as does QMetaObject::invokeMethod(paThread, [=]() { g_idle_add(idle_callback, data);}, Qt::QueuedConnection) but evidently I forgot that doesn't automatically create an event loop. The delayed call to g_idle_add is thus never made. So I tried to derive QEventLoop and call paThread->processEvents(AllEvents,1000); or paThread->wakeUp(), neither of which have any effect.
Then I tried to test premises of my simple question above by calling g_idle_add directly from the pa_threaded_mainloop thread, installing a callback that prints a trace. It appears not to be called at all so I'm beginning to that that I've been approaching this the wrong way alltogether?
I'm not seeing any hooks into g_idle_XXXX via libpulse(), not even a way to obtain a "we're idle" signal. Should I just replace that g_idle callback by one that gets called periodically by Qt itself?

Well, doh. I could have spared myself a lot of work if I had peeked at the libpulse implementation first.
The pa_threaded_mainloop implementation isn't based on GLib at all. In addition, the function called by the idle_callback mostly does GUI-related stuff that has to be executed on the main thread - which is where we are when that callback needs to be registered.
Since there is no way to execute the callback when the pa_threaded_mainloop goes idle I decided to evoke it when the main event dispatcher goes idle (or some approximation thereof):
    if (!idle_source) {
        idle_source = 1;
        // Do the Qt equivalent of having idle_callback() execute when the event pump is idle:
        pvcApp->sendPostedEvents(nullptr, 0);
        pvcApp->eventDispatcher()->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
        idle_callback(data); // resets idle_source
    }

I'm not entirely happy because the whole callback design was clearly meant to aggregate multiple update events for the multiple aspects of a GUI display into a single call to a function that updates the entire GUI. I've not been able to detect any recursive calling of that code snippet above so I'm not losing update events; I guess that's the most important thing here.
